How to replicate the production version of a ReactJS web app into the debugging versions of the app using firebase firestore?
I have two versions of a web application built using ReactJS and Firebase. One version is being used in realtime  (production) while the other is for debugging purpose.
We have no backup for the realtime using version and it has large amount of data. So when we test the app in debug version then it is not replicated properly as the debug version doesn't contain large data.
So what are the possible solutions to sync the production and debugging versions of the app using firebase Firestore so that we can see the how the new features added in the debug version works with the large data in the production version.
No idea to fix it that's why I need some guidance.
